# How can rails remove a table row after an ajax call to delete it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

If I have a link -

```
= link_to 'ajaX', 
  ajax_delete_link_path(link), 
  data: { :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :remote => true }
```

with a route:

```
get 'ajax_delete_link/:id', to: 'links#ajax_delete_link', as: :ajax_delete_link
```

and a link controller:

```
def ajax_delete_link
  @link = Link.find(params[:id])
  @link.destroy
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end 
end
```

and `ajax_delete_link.js.erb` with

```
var element = document.getElementById("id");
element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
# This is the part that doesn't work. Not sure how to access the id
```

The controller deletes the database record but doesn't update the page.  I am trying to remove the parent table row of the td that contains the a

html for that is

```
        ...
        <td>
          <a href="/ajax_delete_link/396" data-confirm="Are you sure?" data-remote="true">ajaX</a>
        </td>
```

Answer (score 3):

You'll be best doing the following

---

**Structure**

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :links #-> will provide DELETE domain.com/ajax/:id as destroy action
```

Your routes need to be structured around `objects`. Considering you're trying to create a `destroy` action, you should be able to send an ajax request to it to get it to work properly

This will give you the ability to do the following:

```
#app/views/controller/your_page.html.erb
<%= link_to "Ajax", link_path(link), method: :delete, id: link.id, data: { confirm: "Really?", remote: true } %>
```

This will send an ajax ([XHR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest)) request to your `links` controller `destroy` action, which you can populate as follows:

```
#app/controllers/links_controller.rb
Class LinksController < ApplicationController
   def destroy
       @link = Link.find parmas[:id]
       @link.destroy
   end
end
```

--

**Response**

The response you have is directly associated with how you're managing the [`mime type`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Mime/Type.html) 
in your controller.

If you use the `format.js` technique, you can call the `@instance method` set in your controller to remove the element in question. If you use the standard Ajax callbacks, you'll have a different challenge:

```
#app/controllers/links_controller.rb
Class LinksController < ApplicationController
   def destroy
     ...
     respond_to do |format|
       format.js #-> loads /links/destroy.js.erb
       format.html { redirect_to(links_url) }
      end
   end
end
```

This will give you the ability to create the following:

```
#app/views/links/destroy.js.erb
var element = document.getElementById("<%=j @link.id %>");
element.parentNode.parentNode.remove();
```

Alternatively, you can use the `ajax` [`success` function to facilitate the callback](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/wiki/ajax), like so:

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
$(document).on("ajax:succes", "a", function(data){
    $(data.id).remove();
});
```

Comment: Do I need remote: true for the html a link? I'm actually trying to modify the code so that both format's are supported.

Comment: Accepted with a few edits - the actual link required a DELETE action as DESTROY was not a recognized HTTP verb - but kept all the rails stuff as delete.  Also puts format.js next to format.html as I use html in another area for a 'regular' (non-ajax) delete link.

Comment: Finally changed the element.parentNode.removeChild() which was removing the link but not the whole table row to be `element.parentNode.parentNode.remove();`  It won't work in earlier versions (7 and earlier but I don't care about them).

Comment: Oh, and I added `remote: true` as I needed that or it would be a 'regular' (non-ajax) link.

Comment: Michael - THANK YOU for the edits! Does the solution work now, or is it still messing around/

Answer (score 1):

I think your question is about how to refer to the element id in your js.erb template. It's a erb, so you can do just:

```
var element = document.getElementById(<%= @link.id %>);
alert(element); //just to see that it's getting to your template.
element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
```

Just reminding that you will need an html element with id set as:

```
id="<%= link.id %>"
```

Comment: Agree, although I believe you shouldn't use a number for an id, better to have something like `id="ajax_<%= link.id %>"`.

Answer (score 0):

As you've seen, making the ajax request changes the database, but doesn't actually update the page. You'll need to have a callback for your ajax that manipulates the DOM to remove the table row you want to get rid of.

Rails fires custom events (check out https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/wiki/ajax) when you use `:remote => true`, which you'll be able to attach callbacks with.

Answer (score 0):

```
<table>
<tr>



    //destroy.js.erb

    $("#row_<%= escape_javascript params[:id] %>").remove();
    <!-- index.html.erb -->
    <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Item Name</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>

    <tr id="row_<%= @item.id%>">
      <td><%= @item.name %></td>
      <td><%= link_to "Delete" , @item, confirm: 'Are you sure?', method: :delete, remote: true%></td> 
    </tr>
    </table>
```

Make sure to handle format.js in your controller method for destroy